# Recruiter contacted me for one position at a company, but I think I'm more qualified for another

Tags: job-search, recruitment, human-resources

A recruiter contacted me today about Job A at a particular company. The company is also looking to fill Job B, but the recruiter didn't mention that. The jobs have the same exact title, I'd just be with a different team. I think I'm better suited for Job B.

**Question:** Should I tell the recruiter to go ahead and submit my info for Job A, while also secretly applying to Job B? Should I tell the recruiter no thanks and apply for Job B myself? Should I ask the recruiter if she can submit my resume for both jobs? Other advice?

Comment: To answer if you *should* or not depends completely on what *you* want and the goal you have in mind... please rephrase your questions as they are currently off-topic (asking for us to make a choice for you). If you care clarifying in comments, I (or other kind user) can help you edit your post to make it on-topic :)

Answer (score 6):

> Should I tell the recruiter to go ahead and submit my info for Job A,
>   while also secretly applying to Job B?

No, tell the recruiter you are working with that you are more interested in position B.  No need for secrets *if* you are going to work with her, and you may come across as confused by the hiring manager if you apply to multiple openings.

> Should I tell the recruiter no thanks and apply for Job B myself?

The real question is *which route is more likely to get you an interview*, using the recruiter or going at it on your own?  This will be hard to answer as it will depend upon the relationship the recruiter has with the hiring manager, etc.  In general if I have a way to apply directly with the company **I do**, as using a recruiter cost the company money.

> Should I ask the recruiter if she can submit my resume for both jobs?

I am sure you can, but this will get tricky as you should probably pick one and apply for it, otherwise you may come across as unsure as to what you are qualified for.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, go for the job you want/feel you’re most suited too.

It works two ways, the job needs to be suitable for you but you also need to be suitable for the job.

If you took job A and it wasn’t suitable or you didn’t enjoy it, you’d regret it and then you never know it might ruin your chance of ever getting job B if that’s the job you want and you’re interested in working for the company.